# ¿Bucle for o while en SQL server?

Tags: sql, bucle-for, while, server

Deseo saber el número de filas de una tabla. Para lo cual aplico la siguiente sintaxis:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tab_1
```

Pero deseo conocer el número de filas de todas las tablas de mi base de datos que contiene 23 tablas. Que se llaman: `tab_1`, `tab_2`, `tab_3` y así sucesivamente.

Hacerlo uno por uno me parece muy excesivo. Estuve buscando en la web si se puede usar un bucle `for` en SQL SERVER, pero al parecer sólo se puede usar `while`.

Entonces ¿cómo podría usar un `while` para poder encontrar el número de filas de las 23 tablas que tiene mi base de datos?

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Comment: Saludos. Dependiendo los permisos que tenga el usuario con que te conectas; te sugiero obtener la lista de tablas (https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/sql-server-list-tables-how-to-show-all-tables/) y con esta información un bucle (`for` o `while`) para recorrer mediante `sp_executesql` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para el `select count(*) from ...` de cada tabla; claro obteniendo el valor que iras sumando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias maneras de obtener el resultado que precisas:

- sysindexes
- sp_msforeachtable
- sys.tables, sys.Indexes, sys.Partitions

**Escenario**

```
Create table dbo.t1 (id int identity(1,1) primary key, col1 int);
Create table dbo.t2 (id int identity(1,2) primary key, col1 int);
Create table dbo.t3 (id int identity(1,3) primary key, col1 int);
Create table dbo.t4 (id int identity(1,3), col1 int);
go
Insert into dbo.t1(col1) values (1);
Insert into dbo.t2(col1) values (1);
Insert into dbo.t3(col1) values (1);
go 10
Insert into dbo.t1(col1) values (1);
Insert into dbo.t1(col1) values (1);
Insert into dbo.t3(col1) values (1);
go
```

La búsqueda en sysindexes por las tablas que necesitas, es muy rápida, pero requiere de
que las estadísticas estén actualizadas, además de que la tabla tenga un indice primario.

**Solución 1:**
Leemos los nombres de las tablas de la vista Information_Schema.Tables

```
go
with c as (
    Select Concat(t.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', T.TABLE_NAME) as name
        From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
)
SELECT rows, c.name
  FROM sysindexes cross join c
  WHERE id in (OBJECT_ID(c.name)) AND indid<2;
      -- la tabla t4 no tiene clave primaria.
go
```

[image: resultados]

**Solución 2**

Recurrir al procedimiento del sistema sp_msforeachtable, para que nos recorra todas las tablas.

```
declare @stats table (n sysname, c int)
insert into @stats
       exec sp_msforeachtable 'select parsename(''?'', 1),  count(*) from ?'
select 
       * 
from @stats t
order by c desc
```

[image: Resultados]

**Solución 3**

Invocar a las propias tablas del sistema.

```
SELECT 
       t.NAME AS TableName,
       p.[Rows]
FROM 
       sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
       sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
       sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
       t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
       i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
       i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
       t.NAME, p.[Rows];
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: No necesitas hacer el join con `sys.indexes`, puedes hacer la relación directa entre `sys.tables` y `sys.partitions`. Tampoco necesitas las condiciones de nombre y objeto. En lo personal, uso la vista `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de revisar algunas publicaciones, lo hice de esta manera. Espero les sirva, si tienen la misma duda.

```
DECLARE @tablas varchar(1000) = 'tab_1,tab_2,tab_3,tab_4,tab_5,tab_6,tab_7,tab_8,tab_9,tab_10,tab_11,tab_12,tab_13,tab_14,tab_15,tab_16,tab_17,tab_18,tab_19,tab_20,tab_21,tab_22,tab_23'
DECLARE @pos INT =0
DECLARE @len INT =0
DECLARE @value varchar(100)

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @tablas, @pos+1) > 0
BEGIN
        set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @tablas, @pos+1) - @pos
        set @value = SUBSTRING(@tablas, @pos, @len) 
        SELECT rows AS NUMERO_DE_REGISTROS
        FROM sysindexes
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@value) AND indid < 2
        set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @tablas, @pos+@len) +1
END
```

Esta sólo es una forma, en la respuesta de [@javi-fer2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/152272/javi-fer2) hay respuestas más interesantes.